# Pandas boolean check unexpectedly return True instead of False

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, series

I was playing around with Pandas. Then I faced something like this. Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
sdata = {'Ohio': 35000, 'Texas':7100}
states = {'California', 'Ohio', 'Oregon'}
obj2 = pd.Series(sdata, index = states)
x = obj2['California']
```

And then I wrote this

```
obj2['California'] != x
```

And this code returned **True**. But I expected it to return **False** since *x = obj2['California']*. Why it is not equal to *obj2['California']* when I wrote obj2['California'] first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what both `x` and `obj2['California']` refer to:

```
>>> x
nan
>>> obj2['California']
nan
```

`nan` isn't equal to anything, even itself.

Note that `x is obj2['California']` is also `False`, as it appears that `obj2['California']` returns a new instance of `numpy.float64` (on my machine) each time it is used.